# Float elements from middle with width in %

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout where two elements float next to eachother originating from the midddle.

I've managed to do this but only when the two floating elements have a fixed width.

http://jsfiddle.net/q7uey80L/3/

Does anyone know how to do the same setup with `width: 300px;` for elements  `.right` and`.left` replaced with a percentage?

If I change the `300px` to say `20%`, the structure fails and the elements originate from the left in stead of from the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do but I suspect float is not the way. This feels like flexbox is going to be the solution.

```
.container {
    border: solid blue 1px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
.right, .left {
    width: 25%;
    border: green solid 1px;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  border: solid red 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  border: solid blue 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.right,
.left {
  width: 25%;
  border: green solid 1px;
}
.right {
  text-align: left;
}
.left {
  text-align: right;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Top titel</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      Quisque viverra ac augue porta auctor. Fusce sollicitudin tellus risus, sit amet commodo felis tristique in.
      <br/>Integer tempor ultricies eleifend. Vivamus id pretium dolor, vitae sagittis massa.
      <br/>Pellentesque pulvinar neque interdum dolor pulvinar tempus. Nullam congue tempus dignissim.
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      Vivamus massa lacus, dignissim ac accumsan non, lacinia in libero. Nullam tempor, velit nec fringilla feugiat, arcu libero viverra nibh, ullamcorper ultricies ante felis non risus.
      <br/>Vivamus feugiat augue nec tellus sodales interdum. Suspendisse ac libero malesuada
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this sollution since it gives me more flexibility. However, the prefix for safari does not apear to be working. Any chance you've come across the same issue? 

http://jsfiddle.net/gn5uyfsb/ Doesn't work in safari 5.1.7 on windows

Comment: I think those version numbers refer to the i/OS versions. For some reason they don't comply with the windows version numbers. 5.1.7 is the latest version on windows.

Comment: Safari is not being developed for Windows so 5 is and will be the very last version for that...so flexbox would not work for the **tiny** userbase of Safari 5 on Windows. You would need fallbacks in any case.

Comment: @Pauli_D I tested with my ipad at home and it does indeed work. I had no idea that safari was no longer being developed for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have another div between the container and left/right divs. You can then give width as percentage, with margin: 0 auto on the container.

```
.right, .left {
    border: green solid 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
}
<div class="container" >
    <div style="width: 60%;margin: 0 auto;height: 200px">
        <div class="left">
           Quisque
        </div>
        <div class="right">
           Vivamus
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/z6s1ddnx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant: https://jsfiddle.net/anjalysaju123/5pypkfky

the css is:

```
h1 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
border: solid red 1px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
.container {
border: solid blue 1px;
display: inline-block;
}
.right, .left {
border: green solid 1px;
float: left;
width: 49%;
}
.right {
text-align: left;

}
.left {
text-align: right;

}
.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of `.container` display is set to `inline-block` and it has no width set. If you set percentage for `.left` and `.right` - percentage are related to containeng element. Set `.container` width to exact value and you can set percentage width for inner elements. http://jsfiddle.net/q7uey80L/5/

```
.container {
    border: solid blue 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
}
.right, .left {
    border: green solid 1px;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```